# SmartStore FMDatabase is not open

Tags: ios, sdk, salesforce, hybrid

I'm developing an iOS hybrid app using Salesforce Mobile SDK. I'm using SmartStore to save sObject information. Although I'm facing some problems. The first time I open the app and log in I receive the following message while registering soup: "The FMDatabase is not open." But if I hide the app and reopen it I can use SmartStore normally. Obviously I want to avoid this. So, any suggestions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Just update the SDK from 1.3 to 1.4